# Are there any private code review communities?

Tags: code-reviews

Similar to this question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/77466/20799, are there any communities out there where I can get my code reviewed. Ideally this would be a private thing between you and the reviewer as it would be large chunks of a full, commercial project, the the whole thing would have to be under NDA or similar.

I'm aware of codereview.stackexchange.com but that's not viable as I don't want to put the code in the public domain and the code would be too big for the format of the Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would head out to your local language meetup group and make some friends. Then you can work something out to review each other's code privately. You can add them as collaborators on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Your best idea is to contract a developer and get him to sign a NDA (non disclosure agreement). Anything posted on any public website will be in the public domain.

Comment: IANAL, but I'm fairly sure this is not true.  Authors retain copyright unless it is explicitly assigned to another.

Comment: Yes, I believe just because you find some code on a website it doesn't mean you have full unencumbered use of that code.